# I want to save image in jpg format from SQL Server database but when I download it , it has only 1KB size and cannot be opened

Tags: c#

```
private void Msg1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)      
{            
   string SaveFileTo = "D:\\DA.jpg";
   // string SaveFileTo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

   // string filename = "jmk.jpg";

   // SaveFileTo = Path.Combine(SaveFileTo, filename);

   CN.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select photo from edistindata  where enrollno='" + CboEnroll.Text + "' ", CN);

   DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   byte[] data = null;

   while (DR.Read())
   {
       data = (byte[])DR["Photo"];
   }

   using (var fs = new FileStream(SaveFileTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
   {
       fs.Write(data,0,data.Length);
   }

   MessageBox.Show("Success");          
}
```

Comment: And how sure are you that the image was saved correctly to the database in the first place?

Comment: As always in this type of question: Please don't build your queries with string concatenation but use parameterized queries. This will make your apps more secure and robust as it will prevent SQL Injections and invalid query syntax resulting from ill-formated strings ...

Comment: `while (DR.Read())` how often does this loop run? Use the debugger to find out!

Comment: Check database.  You may have to increase the max field size from default 1K to a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the code in the question, even it has some of not good coding practices, if the data in the photo column is not corrupted it should produce the image file.
so I have put down your code with proper enhancements that will flag you early before saving corrupted data.

```
private void Msg1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)      
{          
   ImageCodecInfo theJpgCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
       .FirstOrDefault(encoder => encoder.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
   var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
   var myEncoderPrams = new EncoderParameters(1);
   myEncoderPrams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);  

   string SaveFileTo = "D:\\DA";
   // string SaveFileTo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

   // string filename = "jmk.jpg";

   // SaveFileTo = Path.Combine(SaveFileTo, filename);

   CN.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select photo from edistindata  where 
      enrollno=@Enrol;", CN);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrol", CboEnroll.SelectedItem.ToString());

   DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   byte[] data = null;
   int idx = 0;

   while (DR.Read())
   {
       data = (byte[])DR["Photo"];
       Image tempImage;
       try
          {
             tempImage = ByteArrayToImage(data);
          }
       catch (Exception exc)
          {                 
              MessageBox.Show(exc.GetType().ToString()
                              +Environment.NewLine+exc.Message);
              continue;
          }
       var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(tempImage);
       var tempFname = "D:\\DA"+(idx++).ToString()+".jpg";
       tempBitmap.Save(tempFname, theJpgCodecInfo, myEncoderPrams);
   }        
} 

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                return returnImage;
            }
        }
```

The enhancements that I suggested as follow:

1. As @derpirscher mentioned in his comment use parameters not string concatenation when building SQL commands and the easiest most lazy way to do it is `Parameters.AddWithValue()`.
2. Use `CboBox.SelectedItem.ToString` in place of the .Text as been in your code.
3. instead of dumping the byte[] directly through a FileStream.Write() I transferred the byte array into [Image()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.0#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_) then into [Bitmap()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Drawing_Image_).
   this way if the byte[] (and hence the data in the db column photo) is not one of the binary formats the the class Image() can handle it will throw exception and I used that to show the related error.
   Also, this way we over came some issues that may rise if we used Bitmap() directly if the data byte[] contains PNG format.
4. No matter what image format is stored in the photo column it will be legitimately re-encoded as Jpeg then saved.